# Python permutation codes hangs/freezes whole pc

Tags: python, python-3.x, permutation, freeze

My simple code for permutation works for less than 4-5 permutation but freezes whole system and makes all input unresponsive whenever i raise the value ...and i also tried to run it on Android phone (Sd 636) it crashes terminal ..Here's code:

```
import itertools 
 
with open('input.txt') as file: 
    # regardless words are separated by space or newline, parse it 
    all_words = [word for line in file for word in line.split()] 
    all_permutations = [' '.join(item) for i in range(1, len(all_words) + 1) for item in itertools.permutations(all_words, i)] 
 
    with open('wordlist.txt', 'w+') as op: 
        # print(all_permutations) 
        for item in all_permutations: 
            op.write(f'{item}\n')
```

My pc Intel Pentium 4 (no GPU) Kali Linux 2020?1

Comment: Making `all_permutations` lazy would probably be a huge help: `all_permutations = (' '.join(item) for i in range(1, len(all_words) + 1) for item in itertools.permutations(all_words, i))` (note the braces around the outside).

Comment: Thanks but sir I'm just a beginner can I just copy cut paste it (it is my day 2)

Comment: Yes, you should be able to just paste that it without other changes. The change from `[]` to `()` changes it from a list comprehension to a generator expression. The latter only generates elements as they're required instead of all up-front.